# How can I add a header only for a specific PHP file?

Tags: nginx

I want to add a header to a `PHP` file, Nginx already has a location block that checks for all the PHP files, can I add a more specific location inside of it ?

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    location ~ ( /another/lcoation/script.php ?? ) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;

}
```

The header works if I specify it directly, but I don't want to apply it for all the files, it also doesn't work if I try to specify another location block with the path, I'm assuming that it has something to with the `fastcgi`. How can I apply the header to only a PHP file ?

Comment: You could call [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) from within the PHP file itself.

Comment: If you add another `location`, you will need to add the `fastcgi_pass` statement too. The `fastcgi_pass` statement is not inherited from the outer block.